# SCIM - pagination over a result set of more than 2000 records

Tags: api

I am retrieving users on Salesforce using SCIM API. When I try to fetch more then 2000 users (URL = ....&startIndex=2201&count=200) the target throws an exception:

> Start Index too big. Consider filtering down your resultset.

I also so saw this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BaDoIAK where someone else is having the same issue. My understanding is that one can only get 200 records at a time. So how to get users?

Is this a bug in Salesforce?

Comment: 2000 is the max offset in result sets returned via any method - SOQL, REST, SOAP, etc. There's nothing in SCIM that mandates the service provider to honor any (large) offset. You'll have to issue multiple API calls, each bringing up to 2000 recs back and deal with navigation and pagination through them on your own.

Comment: It only gets up to 200 records per API call not 2000. If I increase the count to 201 above, it will not work.

Comment: 200 per page, 2000 max offset.